# How to select only date from datetime column?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a column of type VARCHAR with values like:

```
05:47 PM 09/15/2017.
```

I would like to extract date from datetime.

I have this:

```
(05:47 PM 09/15/2017)
```

but I want this:

```
(09/15/2017)
```

in mysql.

Comment: you shouldn't save date/datetime/time/timestamp values using `varchar()`

Comment: Thanks for your help but I haven't access the database to modify the type of a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the value into a date MySQL recognises, and then [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to output the date in the format you desire e.g.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('05:47 PM 09/15/2017', '%h:%i %p %m/%d/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Output

```
09/15/2017
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to save dateTime values as DateTime type in mySQL which allows you to select date like this

```
SELECT date(yourColumnName) FROM yourTable
```

But in this case, you will need to parse your string either with php or with mysql.
You can use substring method for mysql if every date is formatted likewise.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(yourColumnName, 10) FROM yourTable
```

Where 10 marks the begining of the date in your string.
You can do the same with php, or you can explode your string and then retrieve your date like this:

```
$explodedString = explode(" ", $dateTimeStringFromDB);
echo $explodedString[2];
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help its also working for me but Nick's answer gets desire result in one line.